# smooth scroll doesnt anchor point first time with fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I have a smooth scroll with `jquery`, and a fixed header. I get the height of the header and scroll to top of anchor minus the offest. This works except for the first exception.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      var h = $(".header_wrapper").outerHeight();

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - h
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

Anyone have a clue on How to fix this jump?

Comment: sorry see site here http://windarrahigh.zestdev.com.au/#accommodation